# Filter is not working properly

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have written demo program for servlet filter. here is my code

This is my Test class(servlet)

```
@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        System.out.println("we are in servlet");
        out.println("<h1>hello</h1>");
    }
}
```

and here is my TestFilter class(filter)

```
@WebFilter("/TestFilter")
public class TestFilter implements Filter {
    public TestFilter() {}
    public void destroy() {}

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("we are in Filter One");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {}
}
```

in both classes I have written print statement for checking that, is TestFilter executing before Test (class).

but I am getting output as

```
we are in servlet
```

when TestFilter is going to execute???

Comment: where is mapping code of your filter

Comment: @ankit: it's already in the question.

Answer (score 5):

In this case, never. You've mapped the `Filter` to the url `/TestFiler`, which isn't getting hit, `/Test` is.

Change it to

```
@WebFilter("/Test")
```

so that it matches the mapping of your `@WebServlet`.

For your information, any code you put before the `chain.doFilter` will execute before any servlets and any code you put after it will execute after servlets.

```
System.out.println("we are in Filter One, before");
chain.doFilter(request, response);
System.out.println("we are in Filter One, after");
```